# Find an element ID by an other element of value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html code. I want to get the  id value by the input value.
For example: I want to know the  id value which have an  value=number2 => This is the unknown2. How can i do this with jQuery?

```html
<th id="unknown1" rel="0">
<input id="btnSendMessage" type="button" value=number1 class="red"/>
</th>

<th id="unknown2" rel="0">
<input id="btnSendMessage" type="button" value=number2 class="red"/>
</th>

<th id="unknown3" rel="0">
<input id="btnSendMessage" type="button" value=number3 class="red"/>
</th>
```

Comment: $("input[value='number2']").parent().attr('id')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
$("input[value='number2']").parent().attr('id')
```

Example:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log($("input[value='number2']").parent().attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th id="unknown1" rel="0">
      <input id="btnSendMessage" type="button" value=number1 class="red"/>
    </th>

    <th id="unknown2" rel="0">
      <input id="btnSendMessage" type="button" value=number2 class="red"/>
    </th>

    <th id="unknown3" rel="0">
      <input id="btnSendMessage" type="button" value=number3 class="red"/>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

***Note:-***

`<th>` without `<table></table>` will not rendered on browser and hense it will be `undefined`. If you want to make it work then `<th>` must be inside `<table></teable>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var id = $('input:text').filter(function(){
    return this.value === "number2";
}).prop('id');
```